# Problem with getting value from dataset in switch conditions

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements

I have a problem when I want to choose 1 property second one is automatically chosen as undefined. Is it any way to set only 1 value? I was trying to make a 2 functions. First one was getting color value and second was getting model value, but they weren't in the same scope :(

```js
 const list = document.querySelectorAll('.car-menu__li')
    list.forEach(li => {
        const model = li.dataset.carType;
        const color = li.dataset.colorType;
        li.addEventListener('click', () => {
            switch (color) {
                   case "white":
                        break;
                    case "silver":
                        break;
                    case "black":
                        break;
                    case "gold":
                        break;
                    case "red":
                        break;
                    case "orange":
                        break;
                    case "yellow":
                        break;
                    case "pink":
                        break;
                    case "violet":
                        break;
                    case "blue":
                        break;
                    case "green":
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
   
           switch (model) {
                    case "bmw":
                        break
                    case "mazda":
                        break;
                    case "mazda_wagon":
                        break;
                    case "mercedes":
                        break;
                    case "range":
                        break;
                    case "vw":
                        break;
                    case "fiat":
                        break;
                    case "van":
                        break;
                    case "minibus":
                        break;
                    case "bus_scania":
                        break;
                    case "truck":
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            console.log(`src="car/${model}/${color}"`);
        })
    })
```

```css
nav{
display: flex;
}
.car-menu {
     height: 60vh;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     width: 12vw;
     position: absolute;
}
 .car-menu__model-list {
     width: 12vw;
}
 .car-menu__color-list {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
     width: 12vw;
}
 .car-menu__li {
     width: 100%;
}
 .car-menu__li img {
     object-fit: cover;
     width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <nav class="car-menu">
            <ul class="car-menu__model-list">
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-car-type="bmw">bmw</li>
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-car-type="mazda">mazda</li>
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-car-type="mazda_wagon">mazda_wagon
                </li>
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-car-type="mercedes">mercedes
                </li>
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-car-type="range">range
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-car-type="vw">vw</li>
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-car-type="fiat">fiat</li>
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-car-type="van">van</li>
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-car-type="minibus">minibus</li>
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-car-type="bus_scania">bus_scania</li>
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-car-type="truck">truck</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="car-menu__color-list">
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-color-type="white">white</li>
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-color-type="silver">silver</li>
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-color-type="black">black</li>
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-color-type="gold">gold</li>
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-color-type="red">red</li>
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-color-type="orange">orange</li>
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-color-type="yellow">yellow</li>
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-color-type="pink">pink</li>
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-color-type="violet">violet</li>
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-color-type="blue">blue</li>
                <li class="car-menu__li" data-color-type="green">green</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

ed.

Is it any solution for that?

Comment: Right now you can only either select a car type *or* a color type, but not both. Could you explain how it should work? Or what do you expect what should happen?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier imagine that is a car configurator and you want to choose color and model. If you choose for example red color src will be look like this "car/bmw/red/" but if you choose other model src will be look like this "car/mercedes/red". Do you understand now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would need the `switch` (it does nothing at all). Using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation), this may be an idea (shortened to a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))?

```js
let choices = {
  carChoice: "bmw",
  colorChoice: "white",
};

document.addEventListener("click", pickModelAndColor);

function pickModelAndColor(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target;
  if (origin.dataset.colorType || origin.dataset.carType) {
    console.clear();
    choices.carChoice = origin.dataset.carType || choices.carChoice;
    choices.colorChoice = origin.dataset.colorType || choices.colorChoice;
    console.log(`src="car/${choices.carChoice}/${choices.colorChoice}"`);
  }
}
```

```css
nav, .car-menu__color-list   {
  display: flex;
}

.car-menu__model-list {
  width: 12vw;
}

.car-menu__color-list {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 12vw;
}

.car-menu__li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav class="car-menu">
  <ul class="car-menu__model-list">
    <li class="car-menu__li" data-car-type="bmw">bmw</li>
    <li class="car-menu__li" data-car-type="mazda">mazda</li>
    <li class="car-menu__li" data-car-type="mazda_wagon">mazda_wagon</li>
    <li class="car-menu__li" data-car-type="mercedes">mercedes</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="car-menu__color-list">
    <li class="car-menu__li" data-color-type="white">white</li>
    <li class="car-menu__li" data-color-type="silver">silver</li>
    <li class="car-menu__li" data-color-type="black">black</li>
    <li class="car-menu__li" data-color-type="gold">gold</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I'm really appreciate, I'm still learning and don't know as many things as you. Thanks sir!

Answer (score 1):

If it is a configurator like application, then I'd go for a form-based approach. So instead of using data attributes on your list element, use radio inputs. You can style these inputs pretty good if you set up your HTML in the right way.

A benefit with this approach is that you can set default selected items with the `checked` attribute on a radio input. So your initial load of this page would already have some options pre-selected.

The JavaScript section will also be much shorter as the form is doing most of the heavy lifting. All you have to do is to listen for the `change` event on the form and get the `car-model` and `car-color` values from the form.

It is unclear what your purpose is with the `switch` statement, though now you can pass both values in a single function to these statements.

```js
const configurator = document.getElementById('configurator');
const output = document.getElementById('output'); // Output is only here to show the result.

configurator.addEventListener('change', event => {
  const formData = new FormData(configurator);
  const model = formData.get('car-model');
  const color = formData.get('car-color');
  
  switch (model) {
    case "bmw":
      break
    case "mazda":
      break;
    case "mazda_wagon":
      break;
    case "mercedes":
      break;
    case "range":
      break;
    case "vw":
      break;
    case "fiat":
      break;
    case "van":
      break;
    case "minibus":
      break;
    case "bus_scania":
      break;
    case "truck":
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  switch (color) {
    case "white":
      break;
    case "silver":
      break;
    case "black":
      break;
    case "gold":
      break;
    case "red":
      break;
    case "orange":
      break;
    case "yellow":
      break;
    case "pink":
      break;
    case "violet":
      break;
    case "blue":
      break;
    case "green":
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  output.textContent = `src="car/${model}/${color}"`;
});
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

.input-group {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.input-item {
  margin: 0.25rem 0;
}

.input-item label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.input-item label:hover {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.input-item input {
  display: none;
}

.input-item input:checked+label {
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
}

output {
  position: sticky;
  top: calc(0.25rem + 8px);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #111;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <form id="configurator"> 
    <fieldset name="car-models">
      <ul class="input-group">
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-model-bmw" type="radio" name="car-model" value="bmw" checked>
          <label for="car-model-bmw">BMW</label>
        </li>
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-model-mazda" type="radio" name="car-model" value="mazda">
          <label for="car-model-mazda">Mazda</label>
        </li>
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-model-mazda-wagon" type="radio" name="car-model" value="mazda_wagon">
          <label for="car-model-mazda-wagon">Mazda Wagon</label>
        </li>
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-model-mercedes" type="radio" name="car-model" value="mercedes">
          <label for="car-model-mercedes">Mercedes</label>
        </li>
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-model-range" type="radio" name="car-model" value="range">
          <label for="car-model-range">Range</label>
        </li>
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-model-vw" type="radio" name="car-model" value="vw">
          <label for="car-model-vw">VW</label>
        </li>
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-model-fiat" type="radio" name="car-model" value="fiat">
          <label for="car-model-fiat">Fiat</label>
        </li>
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-model-van" type="radio" name="car-model" value="van">
          <label for="car-model-van">Van</label>
        </li>
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-model-minibus" type="radio" name="car-model" value="minibus">
          <label for="car-model-minibus">Minibus</label>
        </li>
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-model-bus-scania" type="radio" name="car-model" value="bus_scania">
          <label for="car-model-bus-scania">Bus Scania</label>
        </li>
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-model-truck" type="radio" name="car-model" value="truck">
          <label for="car-model-truck">Truck</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </fieldset>
  
    <fieldset name="car-colors">
      <ul class="input-group">
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-color-white" type="radio" name="car-color" value="white" checked>
          <label for="car-color-white">white</label>
        </li>
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-color-silver" type="radio" name="car-color" value="silver">
          <label for="car-color-silver">silver</label>
        </li>
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-color-black" type="radio" name="car-color" value="black">
          <label for="car-color-black">black</label>
        </li>
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-color-" type="radio" name="car-color" value="gold">
          <label for="car-color-">gold</label>
        </li>
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-color-red" type="radio" name="car-color" value="red">
          <label for="car-color-red">red</label>
        </li>
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-color-orange" type="radio" name="car-color" value="orange">
          <label for="car-color-orange">orange</label>
        </li>
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-color-yellow" type="radio" name="car-color" value="yellow">
          <label for="car-color-yellow">yellow</label>
        </li>
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-color-pink" type="radio" name="car-color" value="pink">
          <label for="car-color-pink">pink</label>
        </li>
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-color-violet" type="radio" name="car-color" value="violet">
          <label for="car-color-violet">violet</label>
        </li>
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-color-blue" type="radio" name="car-color" value="blue">
          <label for="car-color-blue">blue</label>
        </li>
        <li class="input-item">
          <input id="car-color-green" type="radio" name="car-color" value="green">
          <label for="car-color-green">green</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <!-- For demonstration purpose -->
      <output id="output">src="car/bmw/white"</output>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps you out. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks sir, thanks to you I understand what I did wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

here I modified your code. It will work

```
let color = null;
let model = null;
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.car-menu__li');

for(var i=0;i<11;i++){
    model=list[i].dataset.carType;
    color=list[i+11].dataset.colorType;
    console.log(model);
    console.log(color);

    list[i+11].addEventListener('click', () => {
        switch (color) {
               case "white":
                    break;
                case "silver":
                    break;
                case "black":
                    break;
                case "gold":
                    break;
                case "red":
                    break;
                case "orange":
                    break;
                case "yellow":
                    break;
                case "pink":
                    break;
                case "violet":
                    break;
                case "blue":
                    break;
                case "green":
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
        list[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
       switch (model) {
                case "bmw":
                    break
                case "mazda":
                    break;
                case "mazda_wagon":
                    break;
                case "mercedes":
                    break;
                case "range":
                    break;
                case "vw":
                    break;
                case "fiat":
                    break;
                case "van":
                    break;
                case "minibus":
                    break;
                case "bus_scania":
                    break;
                case "truck":
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        
    });

    console.log(`src="car/${model}/${color}"`);
}
```

your problem was in your for each and the logic to access for two values in every loop. As you wrote in your problem, the second value is undefined, because you are checking only one li value for every loop.

Comment: Thank you, that's what exactly I wanted to do at the beginning :)